# Package installation takes too long in Bash on Windows

Tags: apt, package-management, windows-subsystem-for-linux

In the new Bash on Ubuntu on Windows feature, trying to install a package via `apt-get install`, I encounter the following bug: after accepting the installation of the packages and dependencies, the following message comes up:

`0% [Conectando a archive.ubuntu.com (2001:67c:1360:8001:21)]`

It stays there for about a minute and a half, then the installation procceds normally. The last number (the `21`), ussually changes when installing other package or even within the same installation, but the common factor is this message, which shows up even when trying `apt-get update` or `apt-get upgrade`.

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

On one PC I experienced super slow apt operations, while on the other on the same network it was "normal" fast.

Tried uninstalling WSL, Firewall rules...

Solution: edit the `/etc/resolv.conf` file and replace the IP nameserver with your own (e.g. router/gateway IP address)

Example:

```sh
nameserver 192.168.1.1
```

Answer (score 0):

Two days after release lots of people are seeing your problem and culprit is always the firewall/antivirus that is just not compatible with WSL yet.

Uninstalling the antivirus/firewall is the only thing that works by now.